# Insert ao Banco de dados Dinâmico C#?

Tags: c#, banco-de-dados, sql-insert

Estou fazendo um `insert` e uso uma `model` com os `Getters` e `Setters`, quando faço o `insert` nos valores eu recebo a `model` como parâmetro e utilizo da seguinte forma

> `sql = "INSERT INTO  " + Table + "(" + campos + ") VALUES ('"+valores.nome+ "','" + valores.email + "', " + valores.cpf + ", " + valores.tel + ");";`

Teria como eu passar os Valores Dinâmico pegando ele da `model` ?

Comment: Pelo que entendi, os valores já estão sendo passados dinamicamente, através das propriedades do objeto "valores".

Comment: Ficou sem sentido a sua pergunta, se pode melhorar ?

Answer (score 1):

eu não uso model, mas utilizo o System.Reflection.PropertyInfo para listar as propriedades de um objeto e monto minhas sintaxes.

```
 foreach (System.Reflection.PropertyInfo pr in obj.GetType().GetProperties())
 {
     if (pr.CanRead)
     {
        object valor = pr.GetValue(obj, null);
     }
}
```

aí basta você ter uma lista de campos e a relação entre as colunas para aplicar cada valor corretamente ao seu lugar